# Mean of data with uncertainties and confidence interval

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

My question sounds rather simple, but sadly I have not been able to find an answer online (which is rather strange as this seems very basic, so I apologize if I simply haven't looked well enough)

The problem is as follows: You have $N$ measurements $x$, and each $x$ has an error in it, so for example $x_1 = 0.21 \pm 0.04$. What I'm looking for is a measure for the mean that takes these error bars into account. My first thought was to use the formula for propagation of uncertainty
[image]

Now this gives you an indication for the error of the mean. But how would one combine this with the notion of, say, a confidence interval? For that you would look at the standard deviation, right? I don't see how one would incorporate the errors in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and normally distributed with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$ (i.e., standard deviation $\sigma_i$), then the sum $$
  S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n
$$
is normally distributed with mean $\mu = \mu_1 + \ldots + \mu_n$ and variance $\sigma^2 := \sigma_1^2 + \ldots + \sigma_n^2$. Thus, the *average* $$
  A_n = \frac{1}{n}S_n
$$
is normally distributed with $$
  \text{mean } \bar\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k \text{ and variance } \bar\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2 \text{.}
$$

Now say you have a series of measurements with error intervals, i.e. a sequence of intervals $$
  \left((l_k,u_k)\right)_{1 \leq k \leq n} \text{.}
$$
We are going to interpret that as $X_k \in (l_k,u_k)$ with probability $1-\alpha$ for some fixed $\alpha$ you get to pick. Instead of a sequence of intervals, we can also view this as a sequence of *centers* $x_k$ and *error bounds* $e_k$, i.e. simply set $$
  x_k = \frac{l_k + u_k}{2} \text{ and } e_k = \frac{u_k - l_k}{2} \text{.}
$$
This then matches you notation of the $k$-th measurement being $x_k \pm e_k$.

If we now assume that all the $X_k$ are normally distributed, we can determine these distributions parameters $\mu_k,\sigma^2_k$ from the $x_k$ and $e_k$. We set $$
  \mu_k = x_k \text{ and } \sigma_k = \frac{e_k}{\textrm{erf}^{-1}(1-\alpha)\sqrt{2}} \text{.}
$$ 
This then yields, as we required, that $P(l_k < X_k < u_k) = 1 - \alpha$. Note that if you set $\alpha \approx 0.32$, you get $\sigma_k = e_k$, because the probability of $x$ lying further away than one standard deviation is about $0.32$ for the normal distribution.

We can now compute the mean $\bar\mu$ and standard deviation $\bar\sigma$ of the sample average $A_n$, using the formulas from above, which were $$
  \bar\mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_k \text{ and }
  \bar\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma^2_k} \text{.}
$$
We can turn this back into an error interval by finding $\bar e$ such that $P(\bar\mu - \bar e < A_n < \bar\mu + \bar e) = 1 - \alpha$. This yields $$
  \bar e = \bar\sigma \sqrt{2} \textrm{erf}^{-1}(1-\alpha) \text{.}
$$

If we put it all together, we get for measurements $x_k \pm e_k$ that the *average* is $$
  \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right) \pm \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^2_k}\right)  \text{.}
$$
Note that the result is independent of the $\alpha$ we picked, and thus holds for every $\alpha$, i.e. every assumed probability that the true results lies within the error interval. Also note that the error bound decreases as $n$ increases, but not linearly but with factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus, to *half* the length of the error interval of the average, you need to quadruple the number of measurements.

Comment: Hm, I almost follow completely, except for the part where the errors in $x_k$ come in. How do I simply add up values with error bars, as I would if $x_k$ had no errors?

Comment: @user3183724 I tried to explain things in more details, and state the actual formula you use.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: So you just give the relations for the straight mean (sum/$n$) of the measurements. But if the related uncertainties $\sigma_i$ are very different, wouldn't you want to give more weight to the more accurate measurements?